# How to tell what version(s) of vb are installed on a windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, vb6

I'm looking for a command line arg that shows me what version(s) of vb are installed on my windows 7 dev machine.

Specifically I'm looking for VB6 information - if it's setup -what dll's are registered/etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To what end? If you're interested in knowing from an installer point of view, about the only thing you can do is check the SYSTEM folder for the MSVBVM60.dll file (and possibly others depending on what parts of VB6 you've made use of).
But that file doesn't HAVE to be in SYSTEM32, it could be anywhere on the path, or in the app's folder itself.